# Microsoft Dynamics FlowFields in Tableau not showing

Tags: tableau-api, microsoft-dynamics

How can i get data from a FlowField-Column from my Dynamics-Table in Tableau?

I connected my Tableau to my Microsoft SQL-Server. Selected a Table that contains `FlowField`'s and tried to analyse them.

My Problem is that the `FlowField`'s are not showing up in the dimensions-list.

So far my workaround is "rewriting" the join in Tableau. Do reprogram the join in Tableau again. I have the feeling that this is a error-prone solution and a repetitive one as well.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: I am running Dynamics NAV 5.0

Answer (score 0):

the NAV FlowFields are Views in SQL:
The Name of the View is Company Name$Table Name$VSIFT$Number
The number is simply a sequence number, the first FlowField in the table is No. 1 the second one is Number 2 etc. So you can just use these VIEWs in you Tableu

[image]

Cheers!